# How does mysqli_fetch_all order the rows?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm building a site that takes info from a table saved on a mysql database. I have a `.php` file that takes an array of the row like so: 
`$titles = mysqli_fetch_all($tresult);`.

Then, in another file I set it to an array in javascript with the statement below:

`var markerTitleArray = <?php echo json_encode($titles); ?>;`

And then I cycle through that array with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerTitleArray.length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < markerTitleArray[i].length; j++){
                console.log(markerTitleArray[i][0]);
            }
}
```

But now, the title's are in different orders. I feel like the issue is I don't completely understand how `mysqli_fetch_fall()` orders things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all()` doesn't order anything.  Your query's `ORDER BY` clause does. Lacking an `ORDER BY`, a query's sort order is essentially undefined.

Comment: I don't mean sorting. I mean if I have a row that's just "1, 2, 3", does it just print it out "1, 2, 3"?

Comment: You mean the order the _columns_ appear in the result set?  That is defined by their positions in the `SELECT`. `SELECT a, b, c` to define the order, rather than `SELECT *`

Comment: Not at all. I mean if I have multiple rows of titles, like "a, b, c" does `SELECT Title FROM SomeTable` give me "a, b, c"?

Comment: It will select all titles for all rows in the order they appear in the database.

Comment: This is getting even less clear. Do you mean that if you have the multiples of any particular value `a, b, a, c, b, a, c`, will the query deduplicate them?  No, it will not unless you do `SELECT DISTINCT Title...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_all()` returns your rows in the same order mysql does, which is to say it does no ordering itself. Don't be fooled by any perceived order you see in your results - without an ORDER BY clause, your result ordering is not predictable. Don't confuse this with the order being random - you'll probably see the records returned in roughly the same order they were inserted, but that's not being enforced.

If you care about the order, you must use ORDER BY : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: Although, this didn't exactly answer the question I wanted answered, it answered the question I asked and led me to my solution. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to add that MySQL will happily do all sorts of crazy re-orderings to your data if it makes it's joins easier in complicated statements, expect to find rows being returned in the opposite order to insertion if MySQL figures a Desc index is better for it's purpose than an ASC index.

Comment: @FlaqueDeau: you wanted the answer to a different question?

Comment: @Bossie I wanted to know why my titles are not in the same order when I `console.log()` them as when I look at them on my MAMP table on phpmyadmin. They're getting mixed up somewhere, and I'm not sure where.

Comment: @scragar that's a really good point. I think a lot of people new to SQL see results from a simple SELECT * FROM TABLE come back in the same order inserted and assume that is something they can rely on, but indexes and joins can certainly change the ordering significantly

Answer (score 2):

**The order depends completely on the order of the fields of your query**:

```
$query="SELECT a,b FROM myCollection ORDER BY a";
$result=mysqli_query($connexion,$query);
```

This order will impact the array returned by:

```
mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Anyway, `mysqli_fetch_all()` is not a good way to process data (from the performance point of view since it fetches all the data in a single *huge* array heavy to handle and process, especially if your application is not a small one.)